# Why do two similar J verb phrases work, but only one of them works with the dynamic power conjunction?

Tags: j

The verb chain `''-:]` works the way I would expect.

```
   (''-:])''
1
   (''-:])'non-empty'
0
```

It also works the way I expect with the dynamic power conjunction.

```
   'empty'[^:(''-:])''
empty
   'empty'[^:(''-:])'non-empty'
non-empty
```

The verb phrase `''&-:` produces the same results, as I would expect.

```
   (''&-:)''
1
   (''&-:)'non-empty'
0
```

When I try to use `''&-:` with the dynamic power conjunction, J produces a domain error and I don't understand why. What's the difference between this use case and all of the others?

```
   'empty'[^:(''&-:)''
|domain error
|   'empty'    [^:(''&-:)''
   'empty'[^:(''&-:)'non-empty'
|domain error
|   'empty'    [^:(''&-:)'non-empty'
```

Is the message below the line "domain error" trying to tell me anything specific?

My actual use case is to replace empty strings with another string. If anyone has any suggestions for better ways to do that, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question and one that had me digging into my Nuvoc reference for `(^:)` Power Conjunction https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/hatco#Common_Uses_2
I refer to Nuvoc since that is the reference now being used instead of the J vocabulary.

As far as I can tell the issue is that you have a dyadic function (your arguments are `'empty'` and `''`) and you are trying to force it to be monadic with your test `(''&-:)`

```
   'empty'[^:(''&-:) ''
|domain error
|   'empty'    [^:(''&-:)''
```

Domain error often show up when you don't have the right number of arguments, or the arguments that you are using are a type that is not appropriate.

If we change your test to a fork `('' -: ])` it works because now the x and the y arguments are being handled appropriately. The `]` selects the y argument and the noun on the left tine does not require arguments.

```
   'empty'[^:(''-:]) ''  NB. turn the test into a fork
empty
```

Another way that works is to change the x argument into a verb using `"_` which creates a verb of infinite rank and when invoked will return the result that you are expecting. This again gets rid of the problem of the dyadic monadic confusion so that your original test now works. Parentheses around `empty"_` are required to separate the power conjunction `^:` from the verb.

```
   ('empty'"_) ^:(''&-:) '' NB. turn the x argument into a verb
empty
```

Other approaches that you might take are to look at the Amend adverb `}` https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/curlyrt#dyadic